# Dictionary Comparison/Conditional check in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two list of dictionaries in the format:

```
list1 = [
    {"time": "2024-01-29T18:32:24.000Z", "value": "abc"},
    {"time": "2024-01-30T19:47:48.000Z", "value": "def"},
    {"time": "2024-01-30T19:24:20.000Z", "value": "ghi"}
]

list2 = [
    {"time": "2024-01-30T18:34:44.000Z", "value": "xyz"},
    {"time": "2024-01-30T19:47:48.000Z", "value": "pqr"},
    {"time": "2024-01-30T19:24:20.000Z", "value": "jkl"}
]
```

**Requirement** : I need to compare value of "time" key of each dictionary in list1 with "time" key of each dictionary in list2  and if they are equal, will need to form a key value pair dictionary for subsequent lookups.
In the above, list1 and list2  have 2 dictionaries with same time :
"2024-01-30T19:47:48.000Z" 
"2024-01-30T19:24:20.000Z" 
I need to combine value of these 2 to form output as below :

**Output** :

```
{"def" : "pqr", "ghi" : "jkl"}
```

using itertools.product function , i am able to list as below so far but not in the key value pair dictionary as required .

```
import itertools

list1 = [{"time": "2024-01-29T18:32:24.000Z", "value": "abc"}, {"time": "2024-01-30T19:47:48.000Z", "value": "def"}, {"time": "2024-01-30T19:24:20.000Z", "value": "ghi"}]
list2 = [{"time": "2024-01-30T18:34:44.000Z", "value": "xyz"}, {"time": "2024-01-30T19:47:48.000Z", "value": "pqr"}, {"time": "2024-01-30T19:24:20.000Z", "value": "jkl"}]

output = [f"{x['value']} : {y['value']}"  if x['time'] == y['time'] else None for (x, y) in itertools.product(list1, list2)]
print(output)
```

**Current Output :**

```
[None, None, None, None, 'def : pqr', None, None, None, 'ghi : jkl']
```

I'm wondering if i can use lambda function to achieve output as : `{"def" : "pqr", "ghi" : "jkl"}`
Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Can a time occur multiple times in a list?

Comment: Using `itertools.product` will make it O(np), which can be a problem is your lists are huge; Andrej Kesely's solution is O(n + p) which is more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dict comprehension has an `if` clause (at the end), to also filter out elements, like this:

```py
output = {x['value']: y['value'] for x, y in itertools.product(list1, list2) if x['time'] == y['time']}
```

Output:

`{'def': 'pqr', 'ghi': 'jkl'}`

Answer (score 5):

I'd create temporary index to ease the search:

```py
list1 = [
    {"time": "2024-01-29T18:32:24.000Z", "value": "abc"},
    {"time": "2024-01-30T19:47:48.000Z", "value": "def"},
    {"time": "2024-01-30T19:24:20.000Z", "value": "ghi"},
]

list2 = [
    {"time": "2024-01-30T18:34:44.000Z", "value": "xyz"},
    {"time": "2024-01-30T19:47:48.000Z", "value": "pqr"},
    {"time": "2024-01-30T19:24:20.000Z", "value": "jkl"},
]

tmp = {d["time"]: d for d in list1}

out = {}
for d in list2:
    if d["time"] in tmp:
        out[tmp[d["time"]]["value"]] = d["value"]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'def': 'pqr', 'ghi': 'jkl'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a list comprehension, use a dictionary comprehension to get keys and values directly:

```
>>> {x['value'] : y['value']  if x['time'] == y['time'] else None for (x, y) in itertools.product(list1, list2)}
{'abc': None, 'def': None, 'ghi': 'jkl'}
```

Then, move the conditional to the comprehension, so it skips the Nones:

```
>>> {x['value']: y['value'] for (x, y) in itertools.product(list1, list2) if x['time'] == y['time']}
{'def': 'pqr', 'ghi': 'jkl'}
```